# GrowTable method at Concurrent Dictionary in .Net

Tags: .net, data-structures, collections

Can you explain some magic in GrowTable method?

Code:

```
// Compute the new table size. We find the smallest integer larger than twice the previous table size, and not divisible by
// 2,3,5 or 7. We can consider a different table-sizing policy in the future. 
int newLength;
try
{
    checked
    {
        // Double the size of the buckets table and add one, so that we have an odd integer.
        newLength = buckets.Length * 2 + 1;

        // Now, we only need to check odd integers, and find the first that is not divisible 
        // by 3, 5 or 7.
        while (newLength % 3 == 0 || newLength % 5 == 0 || newLength % 7 == 0)
        {
            newLength += 2;
        }

        Assert(newLength % 2 != 0);
    }
}
```

In other .net collections (List, Dictionary) resize method maintain double size.

[See Code, 1478 line](http://code.google.com/p/codesmith/source/browse/trunk/Templates/Frameworks/PLINQO/Source/CodeSmith.Data/Collections/ConcurrentDictionary.cs?r=1991)

Comment: `Dictionary` doesn't maintain double size, it uses primes from a precomputed table.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks. But I don't understand, why size of bucket links equals size of entries? Bucket links should be smaller than entries...

Answer (score 2):

When you store data in a growable array, the decision how much to grow it is basically a space-time tradeoff. If you allocate (and thus waste) a lot of memory whenever you need to grow the array, you get faster execution, because you don't need to resize the array that often. (As far as amortized time complexity is concerned, growing by x% is the same for any x. But the actual speed is different.)

How much does the array grow usually isn't documented (only the time complexity of addition). For example, current MS implementation of the .Net `List<T>` grows to twice the size, but current MS implementation of the C++ `vector<T>` grows only by 50%.

All of this could apply to the entries collection in a hash-table based dictionary, if you implement it in a single array (which certainly isn't the only possibility). But you have to consider the buckets too. They have too a space-time tradeoff, but a different one: if you choose any size, the dictionary works. But the bigger the collection, the less collisions you have. And with less collisions, you get faster lookup times. If you want to have constant-time lookup, the count of buckets has to be linearly proportional to the count of items in the dictionary. So it makes sense to make the size of the buckets array the same as the entries array.

But there's one more thing. If the hash codes have some structure, you don't want this structure to be reflected in your dictionary, because this causes more collisions. Let's say you used account ids as your hash keys. And you assign ids to users in the IT department starting from 0, to users in marketing from 200, etc. Now, if the size of the buckets array was 100, you would get many collisions and thus terrible performance. If the size of the array was divisible by 2 or 5, the number of collisions would go up too.

Because of this, the best size for the buckets array is a prime. The next best size is almost-prime (number that doesn't have many divisors). And as before, there is a tradeoff: computing primes is relatively slow. To make it faster, you can say almost-primes are good enough. Or you can precompute some of the primes, which costs some memory.

With all those tradeoffs, there is no single best solution. For your usage, you could try fine-tuning all those parameters and fine out which is best for you. But library writers have to make them good enough for everyone, or at least most everyone. And the authors of `Dictionary<T>` chose slightly differently than the authors of `ConcurrentDictionary<T>`, for some reason.

The specific algorithm that current MS implementation of `Dictionary<T>` uses is to have a table of some primes up to 7,199,369. It always uses a prime bigger than the twice the current size. For small numbers, it chooses the smallest such prime from the table. For larger numbers, it computes smallest such prime exactly.